# How to sum up matching entries in two columns in excel. Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, formula

I have an invoice tracking sheet with the following columns:

1. In column "F" there are months in which invoice generated
2. In column "G" there is amount for the invoice
3. In column "H" there is status of that invoice payment (Pending or Cleared)

Now in cell "K2" I just want to SUM the total amount that is cleared or recovered in January.

Can anyone help?

[image: Screenshot of invoice tracking sheet]

Comment: Look at the `SUMIFS` formula. You have identified the criteria you want already. There are lots of examples on the webz to guide you. If you try a formula and can't work it out, come back here and post what you've tried and the problem you're having and we can help work it out.

Comment: Or just use a pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

You want an array formula

`=SUM(IF(AND($F:$F="January",$H:$H="cleared"),$G:$G))`

Exit the cell with CTR+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter.

Answer (score 0):

As @PeterT stated:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(G:G,F:F,I2,H:H,{"cleared","recovered"})
```